# Groovy closure return value independent of code structure

Tags: groovy, closures

I have some code in build.gradle

```
test {
    doFirst {
        def profile = System.getenv("...")
        if (profile == "dev") {
            println "1: if start"
            // ...
            println "2: if end"
        }
    }
}
```

and last line ("2: if end") executing anyway, even if profile not "dev"

Looks like groovy don't care about code structure: it simple return last line as result of closure

because if I modify code to:

```
test {
    doFirst {
        def profile = System.getenv("...")
        if (profile == "dev") {
            println "1: if start"
            // ...
            println "2: if end"
        }
        println "3: after if"
    }
}
```

Then, this way, if profile not "dev", then all ok - after checking statement groovy execute line with "3: after if"
Is this bug or feature? :)

Comment: I believe that's Gradle and not pure groovy.

Comment: I also believe this doesn't happen with the supplied code... It's this in a debugger?

Comment: Yes, this only in a debugger, sorry.. (

Comment: It's not running that line, it's an issue with the debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as commented, this only in the debugger - groovy works fine